# issues when setting up kubeflow pipeline on minikube

Tags: minikube, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a minikube running on macos. When trying to setup kubeflow pipeline I got the following output:

```
(base) ~/ml $ export PIPELINE_VERSION=1.7.0
(base) ~/ml $ kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
namespace/kubeflow created
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/clusterworkflowtemplates.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/cronworkflows.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workfloweventbindings.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workflows.argoproj.io unchanged
customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/workflowtemplates.argoproj.io unchanged
serviceaccount/kubeflow-pipelines-cache-deployer-sa created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubeflow-pipelines-cache-deployer-clusterrole unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubeflow-pipelines-cache-deployer-clusterrolebinding unchanged
unable to recognize "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=1.7.0": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=1.7.0": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=1.7.0": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"

(base) ~/ml $ kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/applications.app.k8s.io
Error from server (NotFound): customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "applications.app.k8s.io" not found
(base) ~/ml $  
(base) ~/ml $ kubectl get crd -A
NAME                                   CREATED AT
clusterworkflowtemplates.argoproj.io   2021-12-18T15:28:31Z
cronworkflows.argoproj.io              2021-12-18T15:28:31Z
workfloweventbindings.argoproj.io      2021-12-18T15:28:31Z
workflows.argoproj.io                  2021-12-18T15:28:31Z
workflowtemplates.argoproj.io          2021-12-18T15:28:31Z
```

In particular, what does it mean:

```
unable to recognize "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=1.7.0": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

Is it the root cause for the following error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "applications.app.k8s.io" not found

 (base) ~/ml $ minikube version
minikube version: v1.24.0
commit: 76b94fb3c4e8ac5062daf70d60cf03ddcc0a741b

(base) ~/ml $ kubectl api-resources --api-group=apiextensions.k8s.io -o wide
NAME                        SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                NAMESPACED   KIND                       VERBS
customresourcedefinitions   crd,crds     apiextensions.k8s.io/v1   false        CustomResourceDefinition   [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Please also provide your reproduction steps (yaml files, configuration etc.).

Comment: It turns out the kubeflow pipeline 1.7.0 does not work with kubernetes version higher than 1.22. I used kubernetes 1.21.8 with minikube and there is no problem installing kubeflow pipeline 1.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It turns out the kubeflow pipeline 1.7.0 does not work with kubernetes version higher than 1.22. I used kubernetes 1.21.8 with minikube and there is no problem installing kubeflow pipeline 1.7.0.

Yes, this is correct behaviour.

You have mentioned:

> In particular, what does it mean:

```
unable to recognize "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=1.7.0": no matches for kind "CustomResourceDefinition" in version "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

This is connected directly to [Kubernetes version 1.22 api changes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/#api-changes):

> The  **v1.22**  release will stop serving the API versions we've listed immediately below. These are all beta APIs that were previously deprecated in favor of newer and more stable API versions.
>
> - Beta versions of the  `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration`  and  `MutatingWebhookConfiguration`  API (the  **admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1**  API versions)
> - The beta  `CustomResourceDefinition`  API (**apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1**)
> - The beta  `APIService`  API (**apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1**)
> - The beta  `TokenReview`  API (**authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1**)
> - Beta API versions of  `SubjectAccessReview`,  `LocalSubjectAccessReview`,  `SelfSubjectAccessReview`  (API versions from  **authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1**)
> - The beta  `CertificateSigningRequest`  API (**certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1**)
> - The beta  `Lease`  API (**coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1**)
> - All beta  `Ingress`  APIs (the  **extensions/v1beta1**  and  **networking.k8s.io/v1beta1**  API versions)

As of version 1.22 it is not possible to use `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1`(this API is no longer available) and if you want to install a pipeline using this type of API, you can only use Kubernetes version 1.21.